# undefined offset notice when looping through arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code that loops through a list and post it in an option tag. But I get an undefined offset notice everytime I try to run it.

```
<?php $datearray=array('Jan','Feb','Mar'); ?>

<?php for($d=0;$d<=sizeof($datearray);$d++){ ?>
  <select title="mm" name="month" id="month" class=""> 


                          <option><?php echo $datearray[$d]; ?></option>
                          <?php } ?>

     </select>
```

How do I solve this?Is there a better way on doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because you are using <= instead of <. The sizeof (count) for an array will always be one more than the number of the highest index. This is because the indexes start at 0 of course, but the count is that actual number - and humans count starting at 1.

You could also use `foreach` to iterate over the array.

```
<?php foreach($datearray as $date){ ?>
      <option><?php echo $date; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

As a side note regarding the use of `for`, it is less efficient to put `sizeof()` in the for loop condition. This is because PHP calculates the count on each loop. Assigning the sizeof result to a variable and comparing to that works better.

Answer (score 2):

How do you solve it... by learning how to scan your **zero-based arrays**.

You can't use `$index<=$length` as a condition.

Use `$index<$length`, instead.

```
<?php for($d=0;$d<sizeof($datearray);$d++){ ?>
               ^^^^^
```

And yes, there's a better way:

```
<?php foreach($datearray as $date){ ?>

<?php echo $date;?>

<?php } ?>
```

and an even better one: (PHP ***endfor/endforeach*** syntax)

```
<?php foreach($datearray as $date): ?>

<?php echo $date;?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Oh...some people hav so may solutions to a problem. PHP experts.

Answer (score 1):

It should be <.  Or use a foreach loop:

```
foreach($datearray as $month)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that if you have an array with 10 elements, it starts at 0. Sizeof will return 10 and the array will have 10 elements, 0 to 9. The last element in the array should be 1 less than the `sizeof` the array. So the for loop should be:
`for($d=0;$d<sizeof($datearray);$d++)`